# StoryRange to Array

Tags: arrays, string, vba, types, ms-word

With this code, I'm trying to input text from multiple word files and output them into a single word document, combining multiple files into one.

As a step in-between, I want to place the text from open documents into an array. However, I can't find a way to convert the `Range` object received from the `StoryRange` function into a *string*, so it can be put into an array.

I tried to use the `.text` property, but this results into an *Type Mismatch* Error.

```
Sub CreateSumDocument()
    Dim outputDoc As document ' Stores a new document
    Dim storyArray() As String ' Array; Stores product description

    For Each d In Documents ' Should get the full text of all open documents into the array. But receives 'Type Mismatch' error
        storyArray() = d.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).text
    Next d

    Set outputDoc = Documents.Add ' Creates a new document for the output

    For Each s In storyArray ' Loops through array to insert each element into the output file
        outputDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).InsertAfter (s)
        outputDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).InsertParagraphAfter ' Adds line-break between texts
    Next s

End Sub
```

It seems that the `.text` property may not be a *string* format. Please see the reference below.

**References**

- `StoryRange()`
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845743.aspx
- `Range.Text` Property
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff195101.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text` returns a string but you're assigning it to a string array, not a string variable.

If you want each document's text to be put into a string array, first dimension your array based on the number of documents you have, then assign each document's text to an array element:

```
ReDim storyArray(Documents.Count - 1) As String
Dim i As Long

For Each d In Documents
    storyArray(i) = d.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Text
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Then you can loop thru your array later to combine the strings:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(storyArray)
    outputDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).InsertAfter storyArray(i)
Next
```